# Backbone.js and mod rewrite

Tags: javascript, apache, mod-rewrite, backbone.js, pushstate

So I am playing around with backbone and have gotten to the put where loading direct pages that use pushState don't work properly.  if I try to go to my.url.com/login it gives me a not found page which it should because that directly does not exist.  I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L,QSA]
```

hoever this does not seems to work (thought with it I get a bad request instead of not found).  How can I get pushState url to load properly with mod rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually the first I'm reading of the new history API and how Backbone makes use of it -- pretty cool stuff.

To resolve your Bad Request problem, all you should need to do is prepend a `/` before `index.html`. On my end that redirects correctly internally and passes on the query string as you would expect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.html [L,QSA]
```